# How to put a symbol on top of another with arbitrary vertical spacing?

Tags: latex

I want to design a new operator like the below, where a '⋖' is on the top of a '⋗'

[image]

I tried the following ones, but the vertical spacing between the two operators is still too large. I am wondering how can I reduce the space.

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
$_{\gtrdot}^{\lessdot}$
$\overset{\scalebox{1.06}[1.06]{\lessdot}{\gtrdot}$
$\gtrdot \above 0pt \lessdot$
$\gtrdot \atop \lessdot$
\end{document}
```

I then tried the following solution using the `stackengine` package suggested by samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz, but failed to put the operators horizontally aligned.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{stackengine}
\begin{document}
$\gtrdot$ \stackunder[-1.5pt]{$\gtrdot$}{$\lessdot$}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Have a look at the `stackengine` package

Comment: Thank you. But I met another problem.

Comment: Please don't post code fragments, always make a compilable [mre]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A solution based on `array` with easy control of vertical alignment

[image]

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\begin{document}
X \dotfill{} X
\(\gtrdot\)
\(\begin{array}[b]{@{}c@{}}\gtrdot\\[-8pt]\lessdot\end{array}\)
\(\begin{array}{@{}c@{}}\gtrdot\\[-8pt]\lessdot\end{array}\)
\(\begin{array}[t]{@{}c@{}}\gtrdot\\[-8pt]\lessdot\end{array}\)
\(\lessdot\)
X \dotfill{} X
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 0):

My final solution

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{stackengine}
\begin{document}
$\gtrdot$
\ensurestackMath{
     \stackengine{1pt}{\belowbaseline[-3.5pt] \lessdot}{\abovebaseline[0pt] \gtrdot}{O}{r}{F}{\useanchorwidth}{L}
}
\end{document}
```